# Using COUNTIF function with substring functionality or custom comparation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am able to color/run logic for the column B using COUNTIF function:
(I am checking if element B is substring of any element A)

=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10, "*"&B1&"*")>0

```
test1a  a   TRUE
test2b  b   TRUE
test3cd c   TRUE
e       g   FALSE
f       h   FALSE
```

If I want to use this formula opposite way (I need this for color formatting)
I would like to do something like this:

=COUNTIF(A1, "*"&($B$1:$B$10)&"*")>0

- If any element from B is substring of my current element A

Is it possibe to apply custom comparation for COUNTIF function

Better example (1,0 is what I could achieve, True/False is what I needed - has been answered below):

```
test1a  a   1   TRUE
test2b  xx  0   TRUE
test3cd b   1   FALSE
e       g   0   FALSE
f       h   0   FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the criteria argument is an array of values, the formula will return an array.  You then have to SUM the result to get the number of matches.  eg:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$B$1:$B$5&"*"))>0
```

*`SUMPRODUCT` allow you to do this without entering it with ctrl+shift+enter*

If you don't mind the CSE sequence, you can use something like

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$B$1:$B$5&"*")) > 0
```

or even:

```
=OR(COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$B$1:$B$5&"*"))
```

*in Excel `0` = `FALSE` and the positive integers = `TRUE`*

Comment: Appreciated it, solution works well, I've done it hard way with UDF :)

Answer (score 0):

If any element from B is substring of my current element A => isn't this formula working?

`COUNTIF($B$1:$B$10, "*"&A1&"*")>0`

Comment: Wouldn't this check if part of A1 is in any cell of B column? This would bypass the effect of a cell in column B being part of cell A1.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **array formula**:

```
=LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1:B10,A1)),B1:B10,"")))>0
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

In this case we get *True* because the string in **A1** contains the word *big*.

Answer (score 0):

Enter it as an array formula (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>):

```
=COUNTIF(A1,"*"&B1:B10&"*")
```